# Haskell parse error on Type declaration

Tags: haskell, syntax

The ghci compiler gives me a parse error on input `->` in the following program.

```
Type Point = (Int,Int)
Type Picture = Point -> Bool
```

Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for defining type synonyms is `type`, with a lower-case `t`.